# Install a program on Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, mount

I have a problem with installing programs and apps.

For example I download a program for Ubuntu, mount it with Furius ISO Mount then I tray with terminal and

```
sudo apt-get install nxnsetup
```

and it show me next:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nxnsetup
```

I try it for diferent apps but the result is the same

Comment: The app you downloaded. What is the type of it. Acoording to type, you install differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apt-get is used to install packages located on internet or local network servers.

If you have a local .deb package (which is what Debian and Ubuntu use) you should install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/the/package/package_name.deb
```

Otherwise you should read the instructions that come with your software because there are way too many possibilities that can't be covered here without more information.

According to the package name you've listed it seems you're trying to install something called NX Nastran by Siemens and if that is the case you should check their documentation located here - https://support.industrysoftware.automation.siemens.com/docs/nastran/v9/en_US/tdoc/pdf/cog.pdf - there is a section with install instructions specifically for Linux.

Comment: in this document is right "To run nxnsetup you must have the Korn shell available as /bin/ksh" I can't find out what is that mean

Comment: Korn is just another command interpreter like the Bash Shell (which is the default one in many distributions) and if you don't already have it you can install it via `sudo apt-get install ksh`. You can read more on command interpreters here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_command-line_interpreters

Comment: /bin/ksh: /home/akaciq/nx/nxnsetup: cannot execute [Permission denied]  What can be the reason to have no permisson

Comment: Try running it with sudo in front like `sudo /home/akaciq/nx/nxnsetup`

Comment: sudo: /home/akaciq/nx/nxnsetup: command not found

Comment: What is the exact command you're running when you receive the permission denied error?

Comment: I Install Korn shell like you told me > put in terminal /bin/ksh > then I put /home/akaciq/nx/nxnsetup without command in frond (it like in the instuctions)

Comment: OK, try the following:  
1. Become root via `sudo su`   
2. Type `ksh` and press Enter   
3. Execute your command    

If it still doesn't work make sure that the file is executable via `chmod +x /home/akaciq/nx/nxnsetup` and run it again.  
If that doesn't help as well I'm afraid someone else will have to step in and help you.

Comment: The installation is complete. Now I don't know how to start the software

Comment: There is a section titled "Running NX Nastran" in the PDF with the documentation where that should be explained. It might be better if you read the whole document, though.

Comment: I can't find something useful in the document. In directory of installation  there is a file nxnsetup.pbk I try to start it like the first one - ' ksh: /ugs/nxnsetup.pbk: cannot execute [Permission denied] '

Comment: Pretty sure you didn't bother to read the document. 
There are plenty of examples in section **"5.1 Running NX Nastran"** and in section **"3.3 Using the “nxnr” Command"** the authors have explained what is the meaning of the **nxnr** prefix in the examples from section 5.1. The command you're looking for is `nastran` but that won't be of any help unless you read the manual.

Comment: nxnr nastran input_data_file - I read for some data file but I can't find it in install directory and installed directory .
The installed directory is smaller then the installation and that's way I think that have to run ' nxnsetup.pbk ' file who is in installed folder

Comment: Sorry, but I've never heard of this app and won't be able to help you anymore with it. You might have more luck asking in it's official support forums - https://community.plm.automation.siemens.com/t5/NX-Nastran-Forum/bd-p/NXNastran_forum